# Технологическая схема трубопроводов и аппаратов

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-дизайн, веб-интерфейс

как можно реализовать данную схему на сайте, кто нибудь сталкивался с такими проблемами? Нужна не просто вставленая картинка схемы, а интерактивная схема с которой можно взаимодействовать, кликать на разные участки трубопровода и аппараты и изменять их характеристики. Если у вас есть хотя бы примерное представление пните пожалуйста в нужную сторону. Не знаю даже с чего начать реализацию.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Библиотеку D3 на JS посмотрите, может поможет. Мы с помощью нее строим схему сети.

Comment: Схема будет одна но огромная, как пример взять яндекс.карты или дубль гис. У них на сайтах слева меню которое позволяет взаимодействовать с картой, карта масштабируется и является кликабельной. Вот тоже самое только заместо карты технологическая схема. Какая технология применяется у них? И что посоветуете мне? Под изменением характеристик подразумевается то что когда происходит клик по аппарату открывается модальное окно где можно выбрать состояние аппарата в работе/в резерве и в зависимости от состояния изменяется цвет или анимация аппарата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить вам "дилетантский" способ :)

1. Берете любой векторный редактор, который обычно используется для верстки макетов. Например Figma
2. Отрисовываете схему. В итоге получаете HTML и CSS код и вставляете в свой проект.
3. Далее анимируете и делаете интерактив с помощью CSS и JS

Примерно по времени у вас это займет от 1 часа до 4 в зависимости от навыка.

Comment: Подскажите, а как сделать окно масштабируемым? Пример 2гис или яндекс.карты. Слева меню, а все остальное масштабируемая и интерактивная карта с которой можно взаимодействовать. Какая технология применяется в них? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться библиотекой jQueri UI https://jqueryui.com/draggable/
А так же прикрутить zoom на колесико мышки или нажатию кнопок. Пример найденный в интернете https://codepen.io/Nineve/pen/bYWvgm

Comment: А вообще таких примеров https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&ei=sfZBYJanOPGxrgTZha_4DA&q=jquery+draggable+zoom&oq=jquery+draggable+zoom&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIECAAQHjIECAAQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB46BQgAELADOgkIABCwAxAIEB5Q37AcWN-wHGD-txxoAXAAeACAAV2IAaIBkgEBMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjWw5G06JjvAhXxmIsKHdnCC88Q4dUDCA0&uact=5 много :)